# Get common values from table using ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My code is this

```
user_friends =Friend.find(:all, :select => "friend_id", :conditions => "app_user_id =12345")

second_user_friends = Friend.find(:all, :select => "friend_id", :conditions => "app_user_id = 123321")

common_friends_id = user_friends.map{|uf| uf.friend_id}.to_a & second_user_friends.map{|suf| suf.friend_id}.to_a

common_friends = Friend.find(:all, :conditions => "friend_id in (#{common_friends_id.join(",")}) 
  and app_user_id = 12345")
```

it takes very much time can i do in a sort way please help me

Comment: This code shouldn't work at all, fix/check the quotes.

Comment: give us the actual input array or Hash what you have?

Comment: which query from above is slow? check if you have an _index_ on `app_user_id` in the `friends` table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try**

```
 ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_all("SELECT f1.* FROM friends f1 
         JOIN friends p2 ON f2.friend_id = f1.friend_id 
         WHERE f1.app_user_id = 12345 and f2.app_user_id = 123321")
```

**For Rails 2**

```
Friend.all(:joins=>"JOIN friends f2 ON f2.friend_id = friends.friend_id",
       :conditions =>"friends.app_user_id = 12345 and f2.app_user_id = 123321")
```

**For Rails 3**

```
Friend.where("friends.app_user_id = 12345 and f2.app_user_id = 123321")
      .joins("JOIN friends f2 ON f2.friend_id = friends.friend_id")
```

Comment: slightly messy. won't a self join be better, something like here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642005/self-join-on-a-table-with-activerecord ?

Comment: Isn't `all` with params isn't deprecated? You should use `join` and `where`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should be enough.

```
second_user_friend_ids = Friend.find(:all, :select => "friend_id", :conditions => "app_user_id = 123321").map(&:id)

common_friends = Friend.find(:all, :conditions => "friend_id in (#{second_user_friend_ids.join(",")}) and app_user_id = 12345")
```